# Cannot bind to port, even though tcpview says it's not in use

Tags: windows, networking

Every so often when trying to start up my Java appserver on my WinXP box, it fails to start with an "Address already in use" error when trying to listen on a port. The usual solution for me is to fire up tcpview (from sysinternals), see what's using that port, killing that process, then trying again. Works 99% of the time.

The remaining 1%, however, this doesn't work. The appserver insists the port (e.g. port 1099, not that it matters) is in use, and tcpview insists equally strongly that it isn't.

The appserver is just delegating the server socket creation to windows, so I can't see it being a java-specific issue, although I'm  happy to be corrected on that.

What gives? Is tcpview missing out some corner case? Is there a better tool that would help me diagnose these situations?

Comment: The error is real but the error message content may be bogus. It may have failed to open a port because it is on a non-local IP address, or some other error that may not even be port related.

Comment: If it were because of a non-local IP address, it would be a reliably reproducable error, no?

Comment: @skaffman Were you ever able to resolve this issue?  I am seeing the same problem on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64, from Java 8u112 x64.  If the application is killed, the next time I try to bind to the port I get the error you mentioned (as well as the roughly 1% when I exit the application normally).  The port doesn't show up in the output of `netstat -a`.  The only way I have found to resolve the issue is to restart the machine.

Comment: I have the exact some problem. Windows Server 2008 R2. No solution after 4 days of debugging. I hope that somebody will help to find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Weird. To pinpoint the problem, you could try

> netstat -an

That should also list all ports in use. If it disagrees, the problem might be with tcpview. Otherwise, you'd have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

additionally, you could try

```
netstat -ano
```

to find the ProcessID
and to narrow it down a bit, assuming your port is 8191

```
netstat -ano | find "8191"
```